# Fancybox gallery pop up issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I'm sure i have selected the perfect title for this however, if someone can come up with a better title, feel free to edit. Anyway, I am having a slight issue integrating the jQuery plugin fancybox for my gallery when you click on the image it meant to open a pop window. revealing an gallery [click here](http://thecharlesnyc.com/dev/jperiod/ExpressionEngine/index.php/gallery)

The reason why I have chose to use an iframe is because I want the gallery to showcase both videos and images. Is an iframe the correct format to achieve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        minWidth    : 902,
        minHeight   : 505,
        fitToView   : true,
        width       : '50%',
        height      : '50%',
        closeClick  : true,
        openEffect  : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'fade',
        type : 'iframe',
        preload: 'auto',
        helpers: {
            thumbs: {
             width   : 50,
             height  : 50
            } // closes thumbs
           } // closes helpers
    });
});
```

I'm using the plugin [Montage](http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/) for the responsive elements. If there's some form of conflict between the two plugin's. Can someone correct me where I have gone wrong.

Comment: there shouldn't be any conflict but as far as I can tell you are missing to include the fancybox CSS file (you only included the fancybox-thumbs css file) ... on the other hand, you don't gave to specify `type : "iframe"` for images, you could set the type of content for each link

Answer (score -1):

I recently tried to use fancybox for displaying both images and photos and I couldn't find a suitable solution using it. Instead I used [PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) and I've found it to be very good, with plenty of customisable options. I would advise using this if you're willing/able to switch from fancybox.

To set it up simply set your PrettyPhoto selector

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
```

Then for every link to images and/or videos you want displayed in your gallery, simply add the attribute (with a name for your gallery in square brackets) to the link

```
rel="prettyPhoto[myGalleryName]"
```